# Java Graphs and Deep-First-Search

Tags: java, graph

I am trying to complete an assignment whose prompt is as follows:

> It's the year 2059. You have some free time in May this year and want to visit an interesting galaxy. You will need some machines during your trip and you are wondering how many of them can you take.
>   There are a number of machines in a store. Each machine may need some other machines to work properly, and you want all the machines you take to work. Luckily for you, in the year 2053, a special rule was introduced to make customers' lives easier. The rule says that if a machine A depends on another machine B, then machine B also depends on machine A.
>
> You want to buy K different machines such that all of them will work properly. You are given a String[] dependencies describing the dependencies between the machines. Element i of dependencies is a space delimited list of machines that machine i is dependent on. Return a int[] with all possible positive values for K in ascending order.
>
> Example:
>
> {"1 2", "0", "0", ""}
>
> Machine 0 needs machines 1 and 2 to work
>   Machine 1 needs machine 0 to work
>   Machine 2 needs machine 0 to work
>   Machine 3 does not need any other machine to work
>   The allowed K values are 1 (you take only machine 3), 3 (you take machines 0,1,2) and 4 (you take all the machines). So you should return
>     {1,3,4}

The code I have up until now doesn't pass any of the test cases, but I can't understand why.

```
public class GalaxyTrip {

    Set<String> myVisited= new TreeSet<String>();
    TreeMap<String, List<String>> myGraph = new TreeMap<String, List<String>>();

    public int[] possibleValues(String[] dependencies) {
        int vertex = 0;
        for(String s : dependencies)
        {
            String sv = "" + vertex;
            vertex++;

            List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

            if (s.equals("")) continue;           // no vertices, don't parse
            String[] a = s.split(" ");

            for (String nextv : a)
            {
                list.add(nextv);
            }

            myGraph.put(sv, list);
      }
      ArrayList<Integer> myAnswers= new ArrayList<Integer>();
      for(String thing:myGraph.keySet()){
          int answer=dfs(thing);
          myAnswers.add(answer);
      }
      int[] intArray = new int[myAnswers.size()];  
      for (int i = 0; i < myAnswers.size(); i++) {  
          intArray[i] = myAnswers.get(i);  
      }  
      Arrays.sort(intArray);
      return intArray;
 }
 private int dfs(String vertex){
     if(myVisited.contains(vertex)){
         return 0;
     }
     myVisited.add(vertex);
     int total=1;
     for(String adj:myGraph.get(vertex)){
         total+=dfs(adj);
     }
     return total;
 }
```

Comment: What are the test cases, and in what way does your program fail?

Answer (score -1):

Is it acceptable to have a value of 0 in the returned set?  Looking at your code, for a graph of size n, regardless of its configuration, I would expect that intArray will be size n.  In addition, if you have a component of size 5 and two more of size 4, I would expect based on your solution to see the following result:

```
{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,4,4,5}
```

Notice that you are missing the values 8, 9, and 13, because you never add together any of your results.  It appears to me that you properly handle the dfs and tracking whether or not you have seen a vertex.  What appears to be missing is the handling of duplicate results in the answer (lots of 0s in this case and two entries for 4), and the missing step of computing all possible subsets of summations.

Hint: Use a Set to store myAnswers instead of a List, and throw out any answers with the value 0.  Then, handle the addition process.